# Renaming desktop launcher doesn't rename

Tags: launcher

I'm new to Linux (obviously).

When I rename a launcher on the desktop (example: Google Chrome, Computer) it doesn't rename.

I right-click, select "rename", give it the new name. The desktop icon doesn't get a new name - it retains the old one.

For Chrome launchers, I discovered that I can rename by doing "Open With...", select a text editor, then change the item in there called "Name" (3rd line below):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=QBO
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable https://app.qbo.intuit.com/app/homepage?loadCustomerAssistanceAssets=us
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Icon=google-chrome
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=application/pdf;application/rdf+xml;application/rss+xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xhtml_xml;application/xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;image/webp;text/html;text/xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;

[Desktop Action new-window]
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable https://app.qbo.intuit.com/app/homepage?loadCustomerAssistanceAssets=us

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable https://app.qbo.intuit.com/app/homepage?loadCustomerAssistanceAssets=us
```

(From the above I removed a zillion translations of the words "Web browser" - they didn't seem useful.)

But I suspect the right-click "rename" is supposed to work. Help?

--

Edit: In case it matters, I'm on Lubuntu (LXQt).